# How to find an issue with name of the fixed_version_id instead of the id ? (redmine)

Tags: api, redmine

I would like to find an issue in Redmine with some criteria (ex: name of the fixed_version_id, project_id, ...) but I still not able to find the syntax.

The issue I would like to find has :

> a custom field = 113
> an application like BAC
> a project_id = 997
> a fixed_version_id's name = 221200

I tried this :
[https://redmine.xxx.com/issues.xml?cf_113=BAC&project_id=997&status_id=*&fixed_version_id[name]=221200](https://redmine.xxx.com/issues.xml?cf_113=BAC&project_id=997&status_id=*&fixed_version_id%5Bname%5D=221200)

But it does not work. Could you tell me if it's possible please ?

Thanks

H.

I try to find a way to get an issue based on the name of the fixed_version_id instead of its id

Answer (score 0):

With the issue query, you have to provide a version ID. The issue filters can not filter based on other attribites of the version.

You can however use the API to get a list of versions in the project:

```
https://redmnine.xxx.com/projects/997/versions.xml
```

Using this list, you can find the ID of your desired version and use this ID in the second request to get the issues for the version.

The APIs are documented on the Redmine wiki at

- https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues
- https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Versions